# Sort NSFetchedResultsController results by computed date/time

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have an SQLite-backed CoreData entity that has a date type attribute called `timestamp`, it is represented in my `NSManagedObject` subclass as an `NSTimeInterval` (unix timestamp).

I'm trying to sort these entities by the timestamp but only as granular as the minute (not seconds).

I can do this directly in SQLite easily using

```
ZLOCALTIMESTAMP - CAST(ZLOCALTIMESTAMP AS INT) % 60
```

to drop the seconds from the timestamp but need to figure out a way to do this using an `NSSortDescriptor` in conjunction with an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Here's an example of my data and direct SQLite tests...

[image: Data & tests]

I'm pretty sure I could add a transient attribute to the model that performs this calculation and apply the `NSSortDescriptor` to that attribute but admittedly haven't tried that yet and wanted to know if there's any recommended ways of doing something like this.

**Edit based on comments**

OK so I can't use a transient attribute in a sort descriptor. Here's more information about the setup...

The way it works currently is that the entity represents the latest message in a set of conversations and these conversations are sorted by the timestamp of the latest message. As new messages come in they become the latest message for that conversation and therefore the timestamp changes. The timestamp sub-second precision as shown in the screen grab.

The problem is that every time a new message comes in they are re-sorted in the table view and this can happen very often, making the cells hard to tap.

I want to change the sorting behaviour to ignore the seconds and only sort by the minute (see minuteonly column in the screen grab) so new messages that come in don't affect the sorting until the minute changes.

Hope this clarifies things.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You cannot use a transient property in a sort descriptor of a (SQLite based) Core Data fetch request. - But why can't you just sort by the raw timestamp attribute? The relative order of the objects should be the same. Or do you have more sort descriptors, so that it makes a difference?

Comment: I've edited the question for clarification.